# Line breaks with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a working script but it does not work the way I want it to:

```
print('Add as many items to the basket as you want. When you are done, enter "nothing".')
print('What do you want to put into the basket now?')
basket = []
while True:
    myInput = input()
    if myInput == "nothing":
        print('There are ' + str(len(basket)) + ' items in the basket: '+ str(basket))
        break
    else:
        basket.append(myInput)
        print('Okay, what else?')
```

The final line is supposed to look like this:

```
There are 3 items in the basket: 
Item 1: a sandwich
Item 2: two cans of Dr Pepper
Item 3: some napkins
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) with a start index of 1 and `str.format`:

```
while True:
    myInput = input()
    if myInput == "nothing":
        print('There are {} items in the basket: '.format(len(basket)))
        for ind, item in enumerate(basket,1):
            print("Item{}: {} ".format(ind,item))
        break
    else:
        basket.append(myInput)
        print('Okay, what else?')
```

You can also use a list comprehension and `iter` without needing a while loop, it will keep looping until the user enters the `sentinel` value `"nothing"`:

```
print('Add as many items to the basket as you want. When you are done, enter "nothing".')
print('What do you want to put into the basket now?')
basket = [ line for line in iter(lambda:input("Please enter an item to add"), "nothing")]

print('There are {} items in the basket: '.format(len(basket)))
for ind,item in enumerate(basket,1):
    print("Item{}: {} ".format(ind,item))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to separate collecting input and printing the results as follows:

```
print('Add as many items to the basket as you want. When you are done, enter "nothing".')
print('What do you want to put into the basket now?')

basket = []

while True:
    myInput = input()
    if myInput == "nothing":       
        break
    else:
        basket.append(myInput)
        print('Okay, what else?')

print('There are ' + str(len(basket)) + ' items in the basket: ')
for i,item in enumerate(basket):
    print("Item {}: {}".format(i+1, item))
```

Comment: You can pass a start index  of 1 to enumerate instead of adding 1

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, I know, but I prefer to have it from 0. It feels more natural as indexing lists in python starts from 0.

Answer (score -1):

An empty string (just a carriage return) will still be considered an item, even though nothing will be there, which will cause an incorrect # of items in your basket and an empty Item line to be printed.  Consider catching that and ignoring it, or potentially making it equivalent to "nothing" in the second if statement as part of the break condition.

```
print('Add as many items to the basket as you want. When you are done, enter "nothing".')
print('What do you want to put into the basket now?')
basket = []
while True:
    myInput = input()
    if myInput == "":
        continue
    if myInput == "nothing":
        print('There are ' + str(len(basket)) + ' items in the basket:')
        for itemno, item in enumerate(basket):
            print("Item {0}: {1}".format(itemno+1,item))
        break
    else:
        basket.append(myInput)
        print('Okay, what else?')
```